# How to change lines in an angularJS+Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, treeview

I am working with a tree that can be seen in the following [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2nAMFc?p=preview) from the user [Maxim Shoustin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1631379/maxim-shoustin). It is exatly what we need, but I am hitting my head against the lines that show in the tree. I have changed many parameters in the .css and nothing seems to change the lines.

The beginning of the .css is as follows:

```
   .tree {
    min-height:20px;
    padding:19px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    background-color:#fbfbfb;
    border:1px solid #999;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)
    }
```

How can I change the separation between the lines and the checkboxes? And how can I make that the last branch of every subnode is a "clean corner"? (meaning no extra line like in the example).

Any help or reference would be appreciated.

**Edit:** the question seemed not to be clear enough. I have been playing with .css but I really do not know where to change the lines properties. See the following image:

[image]

What I want is:
1)remove the white space between the checkbox and the line.
2)remove this extra piece of line at the corner.
Any idea?
Please note I did not copy the complete .css

Comment: inspect the actual css in browser dev tools for any element in the page. Question isn't clear but look at the `:before` rules for the lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For move the line to the top change this property :

```
.tree li::before{
  top:-5px;
}
```

it works for me !

Comment: I upvoted your answer, it brings me in the right direction, thank you! I will mark it as solved as soon as I find the "bottom" property.

Comment: happy to have helped you, you just can change the top property to "-5px" in this rule.

Comment: Got it! You are right, it works. I used `.tree li {` instead of the `.tree li::before{`. That is why it did not work at the first try. Thank oyu again.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have two class for `div` `tree` and `well`.

```
<div class="tree well">
```

The `well` `class` is overriding `class` `tree`